# How to rewrite path of the loaded atlasJSONHash?

Tags: javascript, loader, phaser-framework, pixi.js

guys!

In the boot.js file I load an atlastexture

```
game.load.atlasJSONHash('MyShip', urlForImages + 'img/animatedObjects/ships/' + playerInfoObject.ship.id + '.png', urlForJSONS + 'img/animatedObjects/ships/' + playerInfoObject.ship.id + '.json');
```

Then I need to load another image with this key and I do this:

```
var loader = new Phaser.Loader(game);

loader.atlasJSONHash('MyShip', configObj.urlForImages + 'img/animatedObjects/ships/' + playerInfoObject.ship.id + '.png', configObj.urlForJSONS + 'img/animatedObjects/ships/' + playerInfoObject.ship.id + '.json');

loader.onLoadComplete.add(function() {
    console.log('done')
});

loader.start();
```

But this doesn't rewrite image...

How can I solve such a problem?

Thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the Cached Assets
`game.cache.removeTextureAtlas` before rewrite it